# Connect Signal and Slots with QPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qpointer

I am creating a GUI application in which I have a dynamic `QComboBox`. I have used `QPointer` to store the `QComboBox *` such that I can avoid a dangling pointer when it is deleted (elsewhere). Even though `QPointer` is supposed to be a smart pointer with conversion operators to the raw pointer type, when I pass it to `QObject::connect()` (new style), I will receive a compiler error.

Example:

```
QPointer<QComboBox> CMB_ItemType = new QComboBox;
connect(CMB_ItemType, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [&](const QString val){ui->TW_Contents->setCellWidget(nRow, 1, CMB_ItemContent);});
```

Compiler says:

```
     error: no matching function for call to 'EditRegionClass::connect(QPointer<QComboBox>&, void (QComboBox::*)(const QString&), EditRegionClass::addContent(QString, QString)::__lambda43)'
 connect(CMB_ItemType, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [&](const QString val){ui->TW_Contents->setCellWidget(nRow, 1, CMB_ItemContent);});
                                                                                                                                                    ^
```

I can make it work by replacing `CMB_ItemType` -> `CMB_ItemType.data()` but why is the conversion operator not used automatically?

Comment: Not sure what you meant with "so that it smart pointer manages the memory leak", but the `QPointer` destructor does not delete the object it points to.

Comment: Then how that object will get free?

Comment: For widgets lke the combobox that is usally taken care of by their parent widget. Or is your combobox a window of its own?

Comment: @Abhi The QPointer doesn't protect your code from memory leaks, it protects you from accessing invalid pointer to QObject. I think you are confusing it with QSharedPointer

Answer (score 0):

My test variant works good:

```
QPointer<QLineEdit> le = new QLineEdit;
connect(le, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &QWidget::close);
```

I think there some problems with your lambda.